# Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: iphone, sdk

This is in my .h file:

```
NSTimer *theTimer;
NSInteger *timeStart;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *theTimer;
@property(assign) NSInteger *timeStart;
```

and in .h file this line:

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
timeStart = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
```

I'm getting error message: Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast from this second line

```
timeStart = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
```

Can someone help please

Thanks,

Comment: Stop trying to assign a value to a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

NSInteger is not an object, it is a plain ol' int basically.  For the majority of cases you just want to do

```
NSInteger i = 10;
```

not

```
NSInteger *i = 10;
```

Comment: NSInteger i = 10; did fix it, Thanks